# Can I use LINE without giving out my phone number?

Tags: privacy, line

[LINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINE_%28application%29) is an app like Skype+Facebook.

Is there a way to prevent LINE from reading my phone number and using it for any purpose? (search/identification/...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid not. If you're not happy with the permissions it uses, don't install it.